# Change and blur events of input field are not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, events, jquery-events

At least IE9 and IE10 have strange behaviour.

I have four input fields and subscribe on their change events. I have logic which disables first input field inside the change event handler of it.

So case:
I enter some value in the first input field, then I click to the second input field. As result change event handler of the first input is fired. So my cursor is inside the second input field and i enter there some value. After that I click on the third input field. So, the expected behaviour is that change event handler of the second input field is fired, **BUT NOT, it's not fired.**

So now cursor is inside third input field, I enter there value and click on the fourth field. As result the change event handler of the third field is fired.

Conclusion. This behaviour I reproduced only in IE9 -IE10. Didn't tested in IE8. In Chrome change handler of each input field is fired. So probably someone had such situation?

Is there bug in IE?

Here is the link to the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/msevera/45fcF/54/)

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <label>First field</label>
        <input type="text"  id="one" tabindex="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Second field</label>
        <input type="text"  id="two" tabindex="2" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Thitd field</label>
        <input type="text"  id="three" tabindex="3" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>Fourth field</label>
        <input type="text"  id="four" tabindex="3" />
    </div>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('input').on('blur', function (evt) {
 var $input = $(evt.target);
    var msg = '<div style="color:red;">' + $input.prop('id') + ' field blur event fired. Value is: ' +     $input.val() + '</div>';    
    addMsgToResult(msg);
});

$('#one').on('change', function (evt) {
     var $input = $(evt.target);
   addChangeEventMessage($input);
    $input.prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#two, #three, #four').on('change', function (evt) {
    var $input = $(evt.target);
   addChangeEventMessage($input);
});

function addChangeEventMessage($input){
    var msg = '<div style="color:blue;">' +$input.prop('id') + ' field change event fired. Value is: ' + $input.val()+ '</div>';
    addMsgToResult(msg);
}

function addMsgToResult(msg){
    $('#result').append(msg);
    console.log(msg);
}
```

Comment: The JS in your question isn't the same as what's in your fiddle.

Comment: Why are you setting `$input = $(evt.target)` instead of `$input = $(this)`?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter. It doesn't affect the result.

Comment: Just updated the javascript here

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that’s strange.

But encapsulating the disabling of the first input field into a small timeout like this seems to “fix” the problem:

```
setTimeout(function() { $input.prop('disabled', true); }, 1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/45fcF/56/